# Scaffolded Identity pages are not being used. It appears that the site is delivering the pages from the un-scaffolded razor class libraries

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have a solution where I am trying to move the scaffolded Identity razor pages from the web site project to a different project, so that they can be shared by a couple of different web site projects scheduled for the next phase of development.

**Problem**: The scaffolded Identity pages are not being used. It appears that the site is delivering the pages from the un-scaffolded razor class libraries.

**What I have so far:**
A solution containing an ASP .NET Core Web App (MVC) which targets the framework .NET 6.0. It was created with an Authentication type of Individual Accounts. Visual Studio did it’s magic and produced all the code and dependencies as expected.

Next, I scaffolded in the Identity pages, which produced the Data and Areas folders containing a migration with the dB Identity tables and the razor pages respectfully.

Next, I added a new project to the solution. I removed the initial class1.cs that the template creates by default.

To this new project I cut and pasted the Data and Areas folders from the web site project to the new project.

I then added in all the appropriate dependencies to the new project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLE2R.png)

Next, I updated the namespaces in:

1. all the razor .cs pages under /Areas/Identity/Pages,  /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account and /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage to match the folder structure in the new project
2. the @using in the three _ViewImports.cshtml files which exists in all three folders
3. ApplicationDbContext.cs
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IGSp.png)

Next, I added to the web site project a reference to the new project with the Identity pages.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n6zx.png)

Then, I opened Package Manager Console and set the new project as the Default project.

Then, I executed PM> update-database.

The solution compiled with no issues and the output indicated the database and tables were successfully created.

I checked the database and all the expected Identity tables were created in the new database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VAhU.png)

Just for reference, here is contents of program.cs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwb5n.png)

Lastly, I modified the login.cshtml file in the new project, simply changing what is contained within the h2 tag.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDJlb.png)

*Thanks for staying with me so far.*

Finally, I ran the project from Visual studio and navigated to the login page.
**The modified login page was not displayed.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9fnE.png)

I have no screen shots for the following but I did these simple debugging steps:

1. moved the Identity razor pages back to the website project and the modified page **was displayed**.
2. put the Identity razor pages back into the new project and they **were not displayed**.
3. Went ahead and registered and logged in. It all worked fine.
4. Logged out.
5. Added a [Authorized] tag to the home controller.
6. Compiled the solution and ran it from Visual Studio again.
7. It, as expected, delivered the login page instead of the home/index page but again it **delivered the page from un-scaffolded razor class libraries and not the modified page in my separate project**.

I have done this successfully in prior projects but those project targeted earlier versions of NetCore and MVC.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: `"put the Identity razor pages back into the new project and they were not displayed"` well, to descibe your concern, identity page usually handled by the `dll files` which you could found at project reference. However, if the `scaffolded` page are different [`you could check here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#next-steps). You can even [`download the source code for identity pages`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Farid. The scaffolding tool extracts the razor pages from the dll and puts them into the website project so you can edit them. So, I have the source code for the pages. What I want to do, is move these pages from the website project to another project in the solution. The reason is I will eventually have multiple websites (student user, teacher user, admin user, etc) and I want all of them to share the same Identity pages.  However, once I move them out of the original web app, the site no longer uses them and reverts back to using the pages encoded in the dll.

Comment: Why are you moving to `another project in the solution` you could do that on that perticular project as well.

Comment: If I used the scaffolding tool on the next website added to the solution, then I would have two different sets of Identity pages to maintain. When I add a third website, I would then have three sets of pages.  I would like to reuse/share a single set of pages.

Comment: Although, I got your concern but if you add the full project as reference does the problem still persists?

Comment: The problem still existed when there was a reference between the two projects.

However, I was able to solve the problem with this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#rcl-lay

I had created a class library but apparently there is also a Razor Class Library template. Using the latter solved the issue. Thanks for you input.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved